# Matplotlib, two x-axes labels on multipanel plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

I would like to make a 3 panel plot (three panels vertically stacked on top of each other), but with two x-axis labels, e.g. from
[here](http://www.astropy.org/astropy-tutorials/edshift_plot.html)

The lower x-axis and top x-axis are applicable to the data in all three panels.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, sharex=True,
                           gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [7,0, 7, 3]},
                           figsize=(14.0, 16.0))
```

with the top panel being

```
ax1. and ax2.
```

and

```
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create 3 subplots, it would be wise not to create 4.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True,
                           gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [7, 7, 3]},
                           figsize=(8, 8))

ax4 = ax1.twiny()

plt.show()
```

[image]